# Namespace Shadowing Class Name

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have the following situation:

A compiled library with the namespace `Library` which contains class `Feauture`.

Now there is another library in development, one which intends to utilize the feature, and that has been dubbed `Library.Feature`. Finally there is a third library: `Library.Feature.UI`.

When working in the `Library.Feature.UI` project, which has both other libraries referenced, VS is yelling a lot about trying to using the `Feature` class, because it is seeing it primarily as a namespace.

I've tried a few different using directives to get around this, as well as trying to qualify the class name, but nothing is working.

Assuming I don't have the ability to change any of the namespaces or existing class names, is there a way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: have you tried using alias directives? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: What do you mean that "VS is yelling"?  This tells us nothing.  Please provide actual error messages.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Really, that tells you nothing... ? My total description was inadequate to determine what the problem might be? I don't need you to Google the Warnings for me, I've already tried that.

Comment: Yes but _we_ need to know the warnings/errors in order to better help you.    The phrase "VS is yelling a lot about trying to using the `Feature` class" is vague and doesn't give us enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use fully qualified names where you specify the namespace together with the type name or you can use a [using directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) to create an alias:

```
using MyFeature = Library.Feature;
```

Comment: I tried exactly this, and I am still having the same problem where VS thinks I am talking about a namespace... I am thinking there might be another issue at play here.

Comment: @Michael: Please add some more specific information about your problem to your question. Preferably a small self-contained code sample that demonstrates the problem. Also, a more precise description of the compiler errors you get (_VS is yelling a lot_ is not very descriptive) would allow us to better help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias directives to give a different name to any namespace, and then use that alias to reference that namespace.

By doing this you can differentiate between the class and the namespace.

write the following on top while using namespaces.

```
using FeatureClass = Library.Feature;
```

For more knowledge on this, you can refer: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Let me know if you have any further issue...

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick (references)

```
using FeatureClass = Library.Feature;
```